# When should one use the comma versus the semicolon, and vice versa?

Tags: punctuation, commas, semicolons

I cannot understand the difference between the comma and semicolon. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Similar to [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1183/colons-and-semi-colons).

Comment: Similar yeah, in that semicolons are involved, but an *exact duplicate* (as someone has stated as his vote-to-close reason)? Hardly.

Comment: Mandatory oatmeal link http://theoatmeal.com/comics/semicolon

Comment: I like this resource: http://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/Semicolons.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [eHow](http://www.ehow.com/how_2181282_use-comma-semicolon-correctly.html):

### Comma (,)

**1)** Use a comma to separate 2 independent clauses joined by a coordinating conjunction such as and, but and or. The key here is to have 2 subject verb pairs.

> Example: The students reviewed for the exam, and the teacher
>   corrected the term papers.

In this example we have 2 subject verb pairs: "students reviewed" and "teacher corrected."

> Example: The teacher corrected the
>   papers and entered the grades in the
>   grade book.

In this example we use the coordinating conjunction "and" but have 1 subject and 2 verbs: "teacher corrected, entered"; therefore, no comma is used.

**2)** Use a comma to separate items in a series to avoid ambiguous meaning.

> Example: Uncle willed me his property,
>   houses, and warehouses.

In this example, we mean that uncle willed me 3 items--his houses, warehouses, and property.

> Example: Uncle willed me his property,
>   houses and warehouses.

In this example, we mean that uncle willed me 2 items--all his property, which consisted of houses and warehouses.

**3)** Use a comma with introductory elements such as subordinating clauses that come at the beginning of the sentence.

> Example: Because the river had
>   flooded, the school closed for the
>   week.

The introductory element, or subordinating clause is "because the river had flooded." It is introduced with the subordinating conjunction "because."

> Example: The school closed for the
>   week because the river had flooded.

In this example the subordinating clause is at the end of the sentence so we do not use a comma.

### Semicolon (;)

**1)** Use a semicolon to separate 2 independent clauses in a sentence, closely related, with no coordinating conjunction.

> Example: The students reviewed for the
>   exam; the teacher corrected the
>   papers.
>
> Example: The candidates spoke to the
>   crowds during Election Day; each
>   candidate spoke passionately about the
>   fate of the country.

**2)** Use a semicolon to separate items in a series where the series themselves contain commas.

> Example: We visited our relatives in
>   Albany, NY; Philadelphia, PA; and
>   Washington, D.C.

Comment: You wrote comma but inserted a period in your "Comma" header. ;)

Comment: @mipadi: Aah, it was a tiring day. Thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: Copying entire pages like this doesn't seem fair to eHow or its author, and - because I doubt it qualifies as fair use - it's probably illegal.

Comment: @ladenedge: Why don't you sue me? If this is illegal, then the majority of the users becomes convicted. I'm giving the source at the top of my answer, and I don't see why it is illegal to share information which was posted openly on another site. I'm not exposing "official secrets", yet I'm giving a useful answer with citation.

Comment: Obviously HG Wells hadn't come across the (2016 update) advice from Lisa Newcomb at Purdue in his _Time Machine_: "... [T]he jerking sun became a streak of fire, a brilliant arch, in space; the moon a fainter fluctuating band; and I could see nothing of the stars, save now and then a brighter circle flickering in the blue." Or perhaps he had but didn't consider himself bound by non-essential mundane constraints.

Answer (score 3):

You use a semicolon (`;`) to create a compound sentence made of two complete sentences. For example: **John went to school; today was his first day.** is equivalent to **John went to school. Today was his first day.** and so is correct.

Use of a semicolon is inappropriate in any other case. The following is incorrect: **Because John went to school; Sally was left home alone.** because if we split into two sentences, **Because John went to school. Sally was left home alone.**, the first is a sentence fragment.

In addition, use of a comma to separate two complete sentences (**John went to school, today was his first day.**) is inappropriate and is called a [comma splice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice).

Comment: You have to use it there, or you *can* use it there?

Answer (score 2):

The first is a comma, which is just a pause that off-sets a phrase. The second is a semi-colon, "[used to indicate a major division in a sentence where a more distinct separation is felt between clauses or items on a list than is indicated by a comma, as between the two clauses of a compound sentence](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/semicolon)."

Comment: The bigger problem for me is trying to remember the difference of usages between semi-colon ( ";" ) and colon ( ":" ). The thing to remember about commas, is that they typically have something that is not structurally necessary to the sentence in them.

Comment: A sentence is, at base, a noun (N) and a verb (V). Everything else is built off that structure. ie, John sits = (John|N)+(sits|V). If you introduce a colon, it could be for this, "John sits: Jane walks away" = (N+V:N+V+A*). But to introduce a semi-colon it would be for "John sits; the world spinning." (the semi-colon join an N+V and some other phrase) (*A=adverb)