# Do I use semicolons to create a list where there are commas in the items?

Tags: punctuation, semicolons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it proper usage to replace a comma in a list with a semi-colon in this situation (see details)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2503/is-it-proper-usage-to-replace-a-comma-in-a-list-with-a-semi-colon-in-this-situat)
>   [When should one use the comma versus the semicolon, and vice versa?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1412/when-should-one-use-the-comma-versus-the-semicolon-and-vice-versa)

I have a list if items that contain commas - in this case city/state pairs.  A co-worker of mine claims that I should promote the list commas to semicolons in this case but I cannot find any style guide which lists this as rule. Is this just urban legend?

example:

> The sales team will visit Portland, Oregon; Portland, Maine; Spring Field, Ohio; and Spring Field, Massachusetts.

Comment: I can't speak for correctness in this case, but it *does* make the list easier to read instead of "Portland, Oregon, Portland, Maine, Spring Field, Ohio..."

Comment: Every Springfield I've ever met has been written as one word. (And there are an awful lot of them. I swear every US state has at least one Springfield.)