# Using Either a Comma or a Semicolon

Tags: punctuation

My teacher was explaining how sometimes a comma isn't enough to make a sentence correct, and that sometimes you have to use a semicolon. I am having trouble figuring out when you should use which.

Can someone please explain?

Comment: An answer appears at the later [Is it grammatically correct to combine 2 phrases into 1 sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233348/is-it-grammatically-correct-to-combine-2-phrases-into-1-sentence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a semicolon when you link two independent clauses with no connecting words. For example:

I am going home; I intend to stay there.

You can also use a semicolon when you join two independent clauses together with one of the following conjunctive adverbs (adverbs that join independent clauses): however, moreover, therefore, consequently, otherwise, nevertheless, thus, etc. For example:

I am going home; moreover, I intend to stay there.

Use a comma after the first independent clause when you link two independent clauses with one of the following coordinating conjunctions: and, but, for, or, nor, so, yet. For example:

I am going home, and I intend to stay there.

Google your query and you'll find it..

Answer (score 2):

Semicolons and commas can be used in many different situations. Here are some:

> Linking Independent Clauses:

```
 Correct: It snowed during the morning; we decided to go sledding. 
 Incorrect: It snowed during the morning, we decided to go sledding.
```

The incorrect one is known as a **comma splice**. Commas can only be used when you have a coordinating conjunction (and, but, or, yet, for, nor, so).

```
Correct: It snowed during the morning, and we decided to go sledding.
```

Another example of linking two independent clauses:

```
Correct: I need money; however, I have no job.
Incorrect: I need money, however, I have no job.
```

> List items:

```
Correct: I like guitars: they can be strummed, which sounds good; they can be picked, which also sounds good; and they look cool, which is used getting a girlfriend.
Incorrect: I like guitars: they can be strummed, which sounds good, they can be picked, which also sounds good, and they look cool, which is used getting a girlfriend.
```

Using commas between each list item makes it unclear what the three list items are. So it is correct in this situation to use a semicolon, but here is an example of list items where a comma is correct.

```
Correct: I am going to buy cheese, bread, and eggs.
```

Hope that helps. Also check out the answer to this question. I believe it will help 
[When should one use the comma versus the semicolon, and vice versa?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1412/when-should-one-use-the-comma-versus-the-semicolon-and-vice-versa)