# Can a semicolon be used before the coordinating conjunction "but"?

Tags: punctuation, semicolons

Is using a semicolon before a coordinating conjunction connecting two independent clauses wrong? Like in this example:

> Some people write with a word processor, tablet, or even a phone; but
>   others, for different reasons, choose to write with a pen or pencil.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should one use the comma versus the semicolon, and vice versa?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1412/when-should-one-use-the-comma-versus-the-semicolon-and-vice-versa)

Comment: Some people will say you can't use a full stop before but; others say it's fine. This is similar. It's a matter of style.

Comment: Simple answer: Really not. The whole point of a conjunction is to not use a semi-colon.

Answer (score 0):

There are three cases where you should use a semicolon to separate independent clauses:

1. When there is no coordinating conjunction between clauses.
2. When there are three or more clauses.
3. When there are commas (for any other reason) in any one of the clauses.

The last two rules hold even if there is a coordinating conjunction between the clauses.  You can almost think of the case where you use a comma (two clauses with a conjunction) as an "exception" (but not really since it's the most common case).

Your example fits case #3; so yes, the semicolon is correct.

For example, the [Chicago Manual of style](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org) has:

> In formal prose, a semicolon may be used instead—either to effect a stronger separation between clauses or **when the second independent clause has internal punctuation** (6.59). *(my emphasis)*

> Semicolons can be used in place of commas when a series of items contains internal punctuation (6.60).

Some have interpreted "series of items" to mean only a list, but it is entirely reasonable for the "series" to consist of independent clauses, as they're larger-order constructs than lists, and 6.59 at least permits the semicolon even if it doesn't  mandate one.

Comment: "Your example fits case #3; so yes, the semicolon is correct." -- Can you tell me which of the rules you give (or any other) makes this sentence correct?

Comment: @MrReality Rule #3 makes the sentence about Rule #3 correct. There is a comma after "yes".

Comment: @Spencer: the commas before and after "so yes" are parenthetical - they are not list commas. #3 applies to lists.

Comment: @Greybeard No. Rule #3 applies to any appearance of commas in one of the two independent clauses, for any reason.

Answer (score -2):

> Some people write with a word processor, tablet, or even a phone; but others, for different reasons, choose to write with a pen or pencil.

A semicolon is conjunctive and mainly used to avoid accusations of a comma splice.

**But** is a conjunction.

You don't need two conjunctions - lose one of them.

Comment: "mainly used to avoid accusations" implies that you think semicolons only exist to placate pedants.

Comment: @Spencer Can you confirm that you are stating that the semicolon and the "but" should both be retained?