# Confusion between colon and dash

Tags: punctuation, dashes, colons

For example, take a look at the following sentence:

> There’s nothing to see — no one can handle you, dear.

What are the general guidelines?

Comment: Possible duplicates (in combination): http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/when-should-i-use-an-em-dash-an-en-dash-and-a-hyphen, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1183/colons-and-semi-colons

Comment: In this case, it looks like a semicolon would be suitable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dashes, in the context that you seem to be using, are used for (emphasized) parenthetical clauses--much like the two prior, but with special emphasis drawn to them.  As demonstrated, parentheses are used for parenthetical clauses with diminished emphasis, and commas for parenthetical clauses--and appositives--with more-or-less equal emphasis with the rest of the statement.

Colons, on the other hand, are used: when building a list, to separate parts of a title, in the salutation of formal letters, and occasionally to introduce quotations.