# Correctly using a semicolon?

Tags: punctuation, commas, semicolons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one correctly use a semicolon?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92/how-does-one-correctly-use-a-semicolon)

I was wondering if the following was the correct usage of a semicolon or if a comma is more apt for this use.

> Well, have we got some news for you; there is a way!

Comment: [This](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1183/colons-and-semi-colons), [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114/when-to-use-a-semicolon-and-when-to-use-a-dash), and [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92/how-does-one-correctly-use-a-semicolon) are related ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The semicolon is not incorrect; a semicolon separates phrases that stand on their own, like in your sentence and this one.  A comma would be incorrect (run-on).

However, I would suggest that a colon would be your best choice in this sentence, because the first clause appears to introduce and point to the second.